# CSS Style Issue for <img> Alt text

Tags: html, css

I am having difficulty getting alternate text to display properly for a html email

here is the img tag

```
<img align="middle" alt="someText" style="color:#54C5D0; font-style: bold;" src=...>
```

The color field works, but all other style attributes (like font-size etc.) are ignored.

**UPDATE**

Hey Guys

So what I am doing is trying to make an html email.

I am copy pasting from my browser to outlook instead of attaching the html as a separate file.

When I view the email in outlook the alt text DOES conform to the color styling but strangely DOES NOT conform to any other style attributes. So the style within the img tag is not being completely ignored, but no font attributes take effect

The code is as above but I have changed to 'font-weight' with no effect.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried putting the image into a container element, and applying the styles to that instead?

Comment: It works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/ym7bqtqp/1/. Also, it should be `font-weight` instead of `font-style`.

Comment: Thanks Guys- changed it to font-weight

Comment: But still doesnt work. The image is wrapped in a container but the container style doesnt effect the text

Comment: This is for an html email, so maybe windows mail is ignoring the style attributes. What is strange is that I can change the color attribute and it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style='font-weight: bold'>
    <img align="middle" alt="someText" style="color:#54C5D0;" src=...>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be `font-weight` not font-style.

```
<img align="middle" alt="someText" style="color:#54C5D0; font-weight: bold;" src="IMG_URL"/>
```

And what the use of adding `font-weight` to IMG tag ?

```
<div style="color:#54C5D0;font-weight:bold">
<span>TEXT</span>
<img align="middle" alt="someText" style="border:1px solid #aaeedd" src="IMG_URL"/> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
style="color:#54C5D0; font-style: italic; font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px;"
```

this code can work for you.